# Replace fields in file inline

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have a file (a.txt) with the following content:

```
Redhat master 12345678 V1A 20.0/20.0.1
Windows slave 12345678 V1B 19.0/19.0.1
```

I want to grep line with the word "master" and replace the 4th and fifth field with a new value.

For example, a new a.txt might be:

```
Redhat master 12345678 V1B 20.0/20.0.2
Windows slave 12345678 V1B 19.0/19.0.1
```

Here "V1A" is replaced with "V1B" and "20.0/20.0.1" with "20.0/20.0.2"

Can someone help to achieve this?

I also want to pass new values as script parameter:

Can I pass new values as a parameter to a script? I was trying below script:

The contents of script (test.sh) is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$2" == "" ]; then
    echo usage: $0 \<version\> \<revision\>
    exit -1
else
   version=$1
   revision=$2
fi
awk '/master/{$4="$1";$5="$2"}' a.txt >newa.txt
```

When I run:

```
#bash test.sh V1B 20.0/20.0.2
```

it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/master/{$4="V1B";$5="20.0/20.0.2"};1' a.txt
```

First we search for lines with word "master" with `/master/` and then replace the value on 4th (`$4`) and 5th (`$5`) field. Final `1` is just to print everything.

Edit:

To pass new value as a parameter you need to use `-v` switch in `awk`, for example:

```
x="V1B"
y="20.0/20.0.2"
awk -v VAR1="$x" -v VAR2="$y" '/master/{$4=VAR1;$5=VAR2};1' a.txt
```

(though beware that it won't work properly if those variables contain backslashes).

Comment: Perfect! It works!

Comment: --------------------------------------

Answer (score -1):

in the line

```
 awk '/master/{$4="$1";$5="$2"}' a.txt >newa.txt
```

"$1" doesn't hold value passed from shell.

you should write

```
awk '/master/{$4="'$1'";$5="'$2'"}' a.txt > newa.txt
```

so that $1 frm calling shell is put in awk file.

Comment: Embedding external input as awk code is a bad idea. The best approach here is to use awk's ENVIRON array. (also note that you need to _print_ those lines).